# How to refine a filter search in widget testing?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I would like to search all the widget matching a given test, check their count, then tap on one of the found widgets - one matching a specific property. How can I do that?

I am doing something like this:

```
testWidgets('My test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  var sideEffect = false;
  await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidget(onSomethingTapped: () { sideEffect = true; }));
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  final myText = "Repeated text";
  final textFinder = find.text(myText);
  expect(textFinder, findsNWidgets(3));

  final tapFinder = find.byWidgetPredicate(
    (Widget w) => w is ListTile && w.title.toString() == myText
  );
  expect(tapFinder, findsOneWidget);
  await tester.tap(tapFinder);
  await tester.pumpAndSettle();

  expect(sideEffect, true);
});
```

I am inclined in "refining" the search, chaining finders or something like that, but I don't understand how to do that (via `ChainedFinder`? How?) and I don't even know what is the best practice.